# Typescript React | Adding 'as const' on variable has different behavior in playground and IDEs (VSCode, WebStorm)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I know I've added `react-native` even though this is really just a `reactjs` question.

#### The code

```
const ScreenStates = {
  DEFAULT: 0,
  ERROR: -1,
  SUCCESS: 1,
} as const;

type State = {
  currentState: typeof ScreenStates[keyof typeof ScreenStates];
};

type Props = undefined;

class TestComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    currentState: ScreenStates.DEFAULT,
  };

  randomFunc = () => {
    switch (this.state.currentState) {
      case ScreenStates.SUCCESS: {
        break;
      }
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

#### The Issue

In VSCode or WebStorm, it will say that `Type '1' is not comparable to type '0'.ts(2678)` but the error goes away if I remove the `as const` from `ScreenStates` variable.

On the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUAcBMEMBcCm1QDMBOB7AtqAFABbzyQDOAXCKfLAMYDWmAbouqgDaYDuAdLTsFjAAbAFYALAGZRk8QHZgcgBwAGMZJUBKUACNEtWAFdSiUAEk0mdAHNM8UPEyhY0FPAKn4AT0iIAUCB+fvwAdtSgAMq06IiIIRE0SKSgALygAN5+oKAAIgCiAGIAguAAMgAq5KAqADRZoHkASo0A8o1VALQAjHXZEeAAwgN5ERFVPX4Avs7JodQA3EHevpGJpmmZ2bSG6DEh8AkIiFXLiJiokdGx8WukANr0iF7nDj5nF1ExcYdJALqLk0WflOoAAClgyKlQIYQtBEKgAJYhZBAub2ahHKo-dYZerbXZxA5rLFXb63Hj5Yplcp1QHZECgcpvUBcWDJbAI0ikJHWIJo0DoWCwnAFGG0KF4bQpAB8uOypC4CPgtAI+AxSD4Oz2RKO2k22VABhMly+NyOpB4-SGIzGcoN2R0MVg9EW9sm9WycNQRnY8HIHoNjsQztdoHdgKAA) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/marqroldan/pen/RwGLOwy) it doesn't show it as a problem.

[image]

#### What I've tried so far

1. Changing the number types to strings (0 becomes '0', error becomes '-1', success becomes '1')

   - Doesn't work
2. Removing 'as const', breaks because any number can then be considered as okay
3. Re-typing `state` variable with `State` type works correctly (with `as const`), but I shouldn't need to because I already added the component?

Edit 3:

4. At first I thought it's because I'm redeclaring it in the class that's why I need to retype it again as `State`, but if I redeclare it with an empty object it tells me that a certain property is missing; which means that it knows that the redeclared state is actually of `State` and yet it thinks that `currentState` can only have one value? What am I missing?
   [image]

**Relevant packages in package.json**

```
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.8.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.8.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

Comment: On the TS Playground or CodePen also show an error if you use `const ScreenStates = {
  DEFAULT: 0,
  ERROR: -1,
  SUCCESS: 1,
} as const;`

Answer (score 1):

The TS Playground or CodePen also show an error if you use `as const`. You should use `state: State`.

```
const ScreenStates = {
  DEFAULT: 0,
  ERROR: -1,
  SUCCESS: 1,
} as const;

type State = {
  currentState: typeof ScreenStates[keyof typeof ScreenStates];
};

type Props = undefined;

const state: State = {
  currentState: ScreenStates.DEFAULT,
};  // Type was missing

const randomFunc = () => {
  switch (state.currentState) {
    case ScreenStates.SUCCESS: {
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I'll update the link in a minute.
But I think I am understanding the problem; I think whenever I declare a member inside the class, I'm overwriting the "type" that it's supposed to have so I need to retype it again. Is that correct? I assumed it would still inherit the type